# Find the Radius of a Circumscribed Circle For a Triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

The question is the following:

> What is the radius of the circumscribed circle for a triangle whose sides are 15, 15, and 24 cm long? What is the radius of the smallest circle that contains this triangle?

I found the height of the triangle to be 9 inches, but I am not sure how to go farther from there. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3t123f3h616496s1_formula_for_the_radius_of_the_circumcircle_of_a_triangle) is a relevant computation

Comment: Let $A,B,C$ be the vertices with $AB = AC = 15$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and $D$ be the antipodal point of $A$ on the circle. The triangles $ABM$ and $ADB$ are similar, so the diameter $AD = \cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Since the triangle is obtuse, the radius of the smalles circle is $\frac{1}{2} 24 = 12$

Answer (score 1):

hint...Use the sine rule in the form $$\frac{a}{\sin A}=...=2R$$

So in this case, $$2R=\frac{24}{\sin(2\arcsin(\frac{12}{15}))}$$